# Is it possible to save margin and padding as a variable to apply to multiple different containers at once in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is is possible to create a larger array to hold multiple style variables?

For example:

```
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.0, 0, 30.0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(26.0, 20.0, 26.0, 0.0),
          child: Text('ABOUT',textAlign: TextAlign.left),
        ),
```

I'd ideally like to apply both the `margin` and `padding` at the same time as a single variable to a `Container`.  Something envisaged like this

```
Stylevariable = 
{
margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.0, 0, 30.0),
padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(26.0, 20.0, 26.0, 0.0)
}

        Container(
          margin:Stylevariable.margin,
          padding:Stylevariable.padding,
          child: Text('ABOUT',textAlign: TextAlign.left),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom class from which you can create variables that you can use for your widgets.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StyleVariable {
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final EdgeInsets margin;

  StyleVariable({
    this.margin,
    this.padding,
  });
}
```

And using in your code:

```dart
var s = StyleVariable(
  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
);
// s.padding
// s.margin
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file with constants and import it where you need:

```
class Constants {
  Constants._();
  static const padding = EdgeInsets.all(10.0);
  static const margin = EdgeInsets.all(20.0);
}


Container(
      margin: Constants.margin,
      padding: Constants.padding,
      child: Text('ABOUT',textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    ),
```